# How do I change htaccess so it

Tags: .htaccess

What it currently does is change url from http://example.com/index.php?link=djasfjk to http://example.com/djasfjk

but it displays the index page. How do I make it so it displays url.php instead of index.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php|)\?link=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ive tried changing:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php|)\?link=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:url\.php|)\?link=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

but that did nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:(?:url|index)\.php)?\?link=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ url.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Only problem with this is if i want to visit a different page on website it sends me to the url.php